AdMob problems for app redirecting to battery optimization settings
My Android app (a GPS tracker) needs GPS data permanently, so it does not work properly with battery optimization. It is possible to warn user if the optimization is "ON". So I do it in a message box. And if the user clicks on "OK" I do a redirect to a battery optimization settings, where the user can switch optimization to "Off".
But after that Google AdMob restricted ad serving in my app and sent me a notification about issues in my app which are caused by problems with "Site Behaviour: navigation"
Then I removed this redirects, published an app update and requested a new AdMob review. And after that it worked again.
But... I think this functionality (switched off battery optimization) is absolutely necessary for my app and the user should know where he can switch it off. And a simple redirect would be the best solution.
So my question: how a redirect to "Optimization setting" (or other screens of " Android System settings") can be made without AdMob problems?
Or maybe there are other ways to solve this problem?
Thank you for your ideas!
